# PHP Can't connect to external Mysql after apt upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 16.10

I have been using external Mysql server just fine, but today I did an apt update and apt upgrade, after that. PHP simply won't connect to external mysql server anymore. I can connect the server via command line using mysql though, but php just does not. I tried simple script to open to connection and

mysqli_connect_error(); just gives out an error "connection refused"

Ports are open. Any idea why this suddenly happened after an update?

EDIT: Updated the client server. The server where external mysql is running works fine, I can connect to it from other servers. But one client server where php script runs can't access it after an update.

Comment: The service hasn't been relaunched perhaps, try `ps auxw | grep mysql` to see if you see a mysqld or mysqld_safe process.

Comment: Did the server restart ? Maybe you opened ports (3306 is default mysql) that you didn't permanently save? Or `mysqld` might not be running?

Comment: Should have mentioned it a bit better. I can connect to same external mysql server from other servers, so this is definitely in the client side, not on the server side.

Comment: Maybe the server your PHP app is on is being blocked by the firewall?

Comment: @giollianosulit, in that case I doubt I could connect via Mysql command line tool. Plus there's no firewalls, ports are open for incoming and outcoming.

Comment: Well can you post the PHP code that tries to connect? Maybe something wrong there

Comment: @giollianosulit you're correct. It was in the code. I had the connection made via "ip:port" which does not work anymore in php 7. Could not also change it in the script I am using so I edited it via ini_set('mysqli.default_port',  'port');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. php 7 does not support ip:port anymore, but port has to be set up separately. Changed the default port via: ini_set('mysqli.default_port', 'port'); in the file where connection was made as I was unable to change it in the script I am using.

Comment: that's good to know, but as far as I know, if you put `DB_HOST` with no port (it will default to 3306)

Comment: It does yes. To the default what you have set up in php.ini. And I needed different port. So the problem was that I could not change the port the old way. Now it had to be set up differently.